# How to follow fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, tesseract, segmentation-fault

I'm developing an android app, with opencv and tesseract for OCR. I used a little of code from basic OCR of [guat.am](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/),

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(ima.cols(), ima.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(imagethre, bmp,true);

        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setDebug(true);
        baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
        baseApi.setImage(bmp);
        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
```

this is not a problem of path or lang or something like that, because this works but sometimes, with some pictures it works but with other not...

How can i follow that error to know what is happening?

The app crash in the last line of the code i posted

Debugging i have seen now that the app crash when calls TessBaseApi.class, specifically this line:

```
String text = nativeGetUTF8Text();
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does it consistently work for some images, but consistently fail for  others? If so, you should post sample images for both the successful and failing cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well i couldn't find the exact way of doing it but the way i did was just printed Log statement after every line and if it fails sometimes then logs till the point will be printed. Therefore letting you know that the line after which no logs were present was causing the error.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt say it but i know wich line fails, i'll edit my question now... But i dont want to now wich line fails(beacouse i know.. :)) i want to know why fails...

Comment: so you are using ndk to get some string from there ryt??